# Angular 5 - how to chain observables in http calls?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am writing an app with Angular 5 and I would like to keep raw http calls in their own services so the other services can manipulate the responses as needed.
For example, I will have a component, component service, and component data service.

How can I chain my observables with this pattern? Here is what I have tried:

licenseData.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CONSTANT } from '../../environment/constants';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class LicenseDataService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getLicenseInfo() {

        const params = new HttpParams()
            .set('unsername', 'swapp')
            .set('comment', "hi");

        const endpoint = '/myendpoint';

        return this.http
            .get(endpoint, {params: params})
            .map((response) => {
                console.log(' response ', response);
                //return Observable.of<any>(response);
                return response['data'];
            })
            .catch(this.errorHandler);
    }

    errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        //TODO: log the error here
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }

}
```

license.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { LicenseDataService } from './licenseData.service';

@Injectable()
export class LicenseService {

    constructor(private licenseDataService: LicenseDataService) { }

    getVersion() {

        //handle the error in here and the loading as well

        return this.licenseDataService.getLicenseInfo()
            .subscribe((response) => {
                return response['versionNumberField'];
            });
        //console.log(' result ', result);

        //return result['versionNumberField'];
    }

}
```

and here is part of my component code:

```
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

    //version: Observable<string>;
    version: string;

    constructor(private licenseService: LicenseService) {
        console.log('Hello Component');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('ngOnInit');

        //this.version = this.licenseService.getVersion();

        this.licenseService.getVersion()
           .subscribe(response => this.version = response);
    }

}
```

My project won't build. How can I chain this properly?

Comment: In your `LicenseService`, `map()` instead of `subscribe()`

Comment: Does my end result need to be an observable the value did not update?

Answer (score 0):

You are can't subscribe to Subscribtion object.

You've got this code in 
LicenseDataService :

```
return this.licenseDataService.getLicenseInfo()
            .subscribe((response) => {
                return response['versionNumberField'];
            });
```

and in LicenseService you try to Subscribe to what LicenseDataService returns which is already a Subscribtion. One of options is using `map` in LicenseService and then Subscribe in Component.

```
  return this.licenseDataService.getLicenseInfo()
            .map((response) => {
                return response['versionNumberField'];
            });
```

after this your `subscribe` in Component should work.

I personally would stay with one service - these operations are not that complicated.

Comment: Look at angular.io docs. Especially Heros demo app (https://stackblitz.com/angular/nnabbgavljx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.ts). You can see that we subscribe in Component and do all the other things in services. You should do all the data manipulation/mapping in service due to Style Guide so I'll give it a shot and call it a good practice. Especially if you want to have LicenseService/LicenseDataService. I personally would stay with one service - these operations are not that complicated

Comment: I want to have 2 services because I am going to have error logging and other things going on and I don't want to bloat my other services.

Comment: So with this separate services I think that's the best option. It does not seems to be a bad practice. You are simply working on data in services and just fetch them in component so everything is fine.

Comment: What can I use as a finally block here?

Comment: Just use rxjs finally block? I don't understand your concern.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177164/discussion-between-user1261710-and-jmachnik).

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to be managing subscription inside of your service unless you absolutely have to.

If I were you I would expose the HTTP service as an observable and use a share replay so that it shares the results when you subscribe to the appVersion through the lifecycle of the app. This way you do not have an internal subscription inside of your services, which is a code smell.

```
    @Injectable()
    export class LicenseService {


          private _appVersion$;

          get appVersion$(){
              if(!this_appVersion$){
                this._appVersion$ = this.getVersion().pipe(shareReplay());   
              }
              return this._appVersion$;
          }

          private getVersion() {

        //handle the error in here and the loading as well

            return this.licenseDataService.getLicenseInfo()
               .pipe(
                  map(response => return response['versionNumberField'] as any
               );
         }     
   }
```

Then in your component, you can inject the service and subscribe to the appVersion$ observable to get the app version value.

The reason I would do it this way It keeps everything in a more reactive programming paradigm and allows you to chain actions together with other asynchronous code. And it doesn't have the subscription inside of a service.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean can you explain more?

Comment: How can I use something like 'finally' in the code here? The docs say finally is not existent on Observable.

Comment: I tried this with the pipe and it gives me this error:    this.licenseService.getWebwiseVersion()
      L27:         .subscribe((response) => { console.log(response); this.webwiseVersion = response; });

            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'. Property '_isScalar' is missing in type '{}'.

Comment: I made a couple updates, first i forgot to add the shareReplay operator that ties it all together, and second I updated the map so it casts the output to any, which should fix the compiler error. if you can access the property  `response.versionNumberField` instead of `response['versionNumberField']`  i would do it that way so it has better typings support

Comment: What are you trying to do with a 'finally`?